# how write hyperlink to local picture into the cell in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink, openpyxl

I use Python 2.7.3
I need to write hyperlink to local picture into the cell by openpyxl library.

when I need add hyperlink to web site I write something like this:

from openpyxl import Workbook

```
wb = Workbook()

dest_filename = r'empty_book.xlsx'

ws = wb.worksheets[0]

ws.title = 'Name'

hyperlink to local picture

ws.cell('B1').hyperlink = ('http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/api.html')

hyperlink to local picture

ws.cell('B2').hyperlink = ('1.png') # It doesn't work! 

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

I have 3 question:

1. how we can write hyperlink like VBA's style function:
   `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
           "=HYPERLINK(""http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"",""site"")"`
   with hyherlink and her name
2. how we can write hyperlink to local image?
   `ws.cell('B2').hyperlink = ('1.png') # It doesn't work!  And I don't now what to do ) 
   Plese, help me )`
3. Can we use unicode hyperlinks to image? for example when I use
   `ws.cell('B1').hyperlink =
   (u'http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/api.html') It fail with error!
   for example we have picture 'russian_language_name.png' and we
   create hyperlink in exel without any problem. We click to the cell,
   and then print
   '=Hyperlink("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";"site_by_russian_language")`

save document, unzip him. Then we go to him directory to xl->worksheets->sheet1.xml
and we see the title

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>`

and then ...

`row r="2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25" spans="2:6">-<c r="B2" t="str" s="1"><f>HYPERLINK("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask","site_by_russian_language")</f><v>site_by_russian_language</v></c>`

everything ok =) Exel supports unicode, but what about python's library openpyxl? It support the unicode in hyperlinks ?

Answer (score 0):

As the files in the `.xlsx` file are XML files with `UTF-8` encoding, Unicode hyperlinks are not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

About Question 2, you need to include the full path of the file link, i think. 
If you cannot access the file link in your Excel file, it's the security strategy of Excel that prohibits such actions.

Answer (score -1):

I answered a similar question. Hope this helps.

Well, I could arrive at this. While there is no direct way to build a hyperlink, in your case we could do this way. I was able to build a hyperlink to an existing file using the below code.

`wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
s = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
s['B4'].value = '=HYPERLINK("C:\\Users\\Manoj.Waghmare\\Desktop\\script.txt", "newfile")'
s['B4'].style = 'Hyperlink'
wb.save('trial.xlsx')`

By mentioning the style attribute as 'Hyperlink' is the key. All other code I have may not be of any much importance to you. style attribute would otherwise have a value of 'Normal' Strange thing is even without the style attribute, the hyperlink we working but just that it was lacking style! of course. Though strange, I have seen stranger things. Hope this helps.